# SeekBar rendering wrong on Android 5.0.2 - can I fix it?

Tags: android

On my HTC One running Android 5.0.2 a seekbar I've added renders like this:

[image: Seekbar with seeker vertically dispositioned]

The veritcal offset of the dot/seeker is what's bothering me. It's not like that on an Nexus 5 I've tested on. Any idea why?

This is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/fa_seekBar"
        android:max="167"
        android:progress="@{model.SeekBarValue}"
        android:onStopTrackingTouch="@{model.onStopTracking}"
        android:onProgressChanged="@{model.onValueChanged}"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:background="#FBB"/>
 (...)
```

Comment: Try <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"/>

Comment: Yeah that worked :) Adding padding-bottom/top compensates for the smaller height

Comment: I think margin is better because it's not the space the SeekBar need.

Comment: Extra: Last time I tested on Android 6 SeekBar height was smaller than on Andorid 5. You might want to test for yourself and increase padding on Android 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from a constant height to wrap_content and compensate with padding if you want a larger click area:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    (...)
/>
```

(Thanks to tiny sunlight)